# Designing 2d animation

Tags: html5-canvas, opengl-es-2.0, svg-animate

i have been asked to compare the following languages and come up with the best to generate 2d graphics.can u please suggest me the best out of them .
Languages are-->webgl,opengl,svg,canvas using html5 
My project is basically to design a 2d animation of a moving object and also designing the background. the object will be moved based on the gps information.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done animations using **html5-canvas** with **kinetic.js**,both your animation and designing the background is pretty easy.

If the animations is done using **svg** files,instead of the normal image files,the amount of data transfer can be reduced,plus manipulation on it will also be easy.

The project that i did was on html5 canvas using svg files.

Unfortunately i havent tried out open-gl.

Refer this link too: [Use Canvas in SVG or WebGL for 3D application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268534/use-canvas-in-svg-or-webgl-for-3d-application)

[This too](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/html5-canvas-vs.-svg-choose-the-best-tool-for-the-job.html#fbid=djPRhjqjo8i)

Comment: thank you.. :)and also can u please tell me that will it be easy to create a dynamic animation based on the data we receive . i mean to move an object according to data .can it be manipulated in html5-canvas

Comment: Dynamic animation? Yeh i guess so...
Erm... like for example i am making a game using html5 canvas which picks up the pointer movements and projects it accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9fnq/11/

Check this fiddle.

Comment: Havnt completed the game though... busy doing other stuff. But yes dynamic animation is possible :)

Comment: Thanx a lot.. :) i will try it out now.. appreciate it..thank you again

Comment: hey i am new to this actually ..m sorry...tell me how do you do that.