# How can connect unity 3d with asp.net MVC ..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-game-engine

I am researching the possibility to render a 3D model or graphic from a building described by data in a ASP.Net MVC webapplication (C#).

Most posts on forums and on stackoverflow and articles on blogs and websites I find about things related are old (2006 and before).

As far as I can tell there are three choices: Direct3D, OpenGL and Unity 3D.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want build game 3d in unity and put it in web page

Answer (score 0):

Your might try http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_svg.asp

I believe all of those technologies must run local anyway.

Here's a few ideas on how to get it to be 3D instead of just vector

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/graphics

Here's someone else talking about it on Stack Overflow

[Use Canvas in SVG or WebGL for 3D application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268534/use-canvas-in-svg-or-webgl-for-3d-application)

Comment: I want build game 3d in unity and put it in web page can I do it